# Rails JOINS with a twist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have been trying and failing for 2 days now :) to get a list of ideas (posts basically) with likes. Order Desc preferably.

I have scaffolded ideas and users which work fine.

Likes (socialization gem) gives me the headache.
I can add likes and retrieve them. And I can also find out how many likes a specific idea has: idea.likers(User).count
and find out whether a user likes a specific idea: user.likes?(idea)

But I can't do agregates because of the non-standard field names which prohibit me from making a JOIN.

```
  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "liker_type"
  t.integer  "liker_id" (this is/should be user_id)
  t.string   "likeable_type"
  t.integer  "likeable_id" (this is/should be idea_id)
  t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "likes", ["likeable_id", "likeable_type"], name:    "fk_likeables"
  add_index "likes", ["liker_id", "liker_type"], name: "fk_likes"
```

Models:

- like.rb - empty
- user.rb - acts_as_liker
- idea.rb - acts_as_likeable

Is there a way to join likes and ideas eg somehow matching liker_id to user_id? Or shall I rename the fields in the table (liker_id to user_id and likeable_id to idea_id)...? And also add these:

like.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :idea
```

idea.rb

```
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
```

user.rb

```
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a different column as foreign key which gets used in joins, you could add `foreign_key: ...` option to `belongs_to` as follows:

```
# app/models/like.rb

belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :liker_id
belongs_to :idea, foreign_key: :likeable_id
```

See referenced documentation on [belongs_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to).

You can also specify join conditions yourself as follows:

```
Idea.joins('inner join likes on ideas.id = likes.likeable_id').where(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Unfortunately joins puts an order by created_at in the SQL which drives me crazy because I need to order by like_count:
Idea.joins('inner join likes on ideas.id = likes.likeable_id').select('likes.*, COUNT(*) AS like_count, ideas.title, ideas.intro').group('likeable_id').order('like_count DESC')

Comment: The default ordering is very likely caused by a [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class).  Plese see the linked document on how  you can ignore `default_scope`s in queries.

Comment: That's it! Done. Huge thanks towards your way vee! :)
ps: now I remember that I set the default scope in the model
ps2: you don't look 33 :)))